# Counts variables that have value and If it meets the condition do what I want

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make that when the input boxes have values It lets the user submit the data to the database. Where input boxes and dropdownlist values must be greater than zero. If the if conditions get filled with values greater than zero the update the database table and insert the data provided in the if statements. I want something like an int count for in which it counts how many conditions get filled with values greater than 0 it lets the user submit the data. that is what I am missing and cannot figured out how to do it. Here is my code:

```
int ContratoProyeccionID = (int)gvContratoProyecciones.SelectedValue;
        try
        {
            int razon = 0;

            if (int.TryParse(txtTotalHoras.Value, out razon) && razon > 0)
            SometerHoras(ContratoProyeccionID, decimal.Parse(txtTotalHoras.Value), 0);

            if (ddlRazon1.SelectedIndex > 0 && int.TryParse(txtHorasRazon1.Value, out razon) && razon > 0) 
                SometerHoras(ContratoProyeccionID, decimal.Parse(txtHorasRazon1.Value), ddlRazon1.SelectedIndex);

            if (ddlRazon2.SelectedIndex > 0 && int.TryParse(txtHorasRazon2.Value, out razon) && razon > 0)
                SometerHoras(ContratoProyeccionID, decimal.Parse(txtHorasRazon2.Value), ddlRazon2.SelectedIndex);

            if (ddlRazon3.SelectedIndex > 0 && int.TryParse(txtHorasRazon3.Value, out razon) && razon > 0)
                SometerHoras(ContratoProyeccionID, decimal.Parse(txtHorasRazon3.Value), ddlRazon3.SelectedIndex);

            if (ddlRazon4.SelectedIndex > 0 && int.TryParse(txtHorasRazon4.Value, out razon) && razon > 0)
                SometerHoras(ContratoProyeccionID, decimal.Parse(txtHorasRazon4.Value), ddlRazon4.SelectedIndex);

            if (ddlRazon5.SelectedIndex > 0 && int.TryParse(txtHorasRazon5.Value, out razon) && razon > 0)
                SometerHoras(ContratoProyeccionID, decimal.Parse(txtHorasRazon5.Value), ddlRazon5.SelectedIndex);

            //Hacer Update a Estatus 
            SqlHelper objHelper = new SqlHelper();
            objHelper.Timeout = 5000;

            using (SqlConnection sCon2 = new SqlConnection(objHelper.ConnectionString))
            {
                sCon2.Open();
                SqlTransaction sTran2 = sCon2.BeginTransaction();
                ContratoProyeccion CP = ContratoProyeccion.Get(contratoproyeccionID: ContratoProyeccionID).First();
                CP.Estatus = "R";
                ContratoProyeccion.Update(sCon2, sTran2, CP);

                sTran2.Commit();
                      }

            pnlRegistro.Visible = false;
            ddlRazon1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlRazon2.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlRazon3.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlRazon4.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlRazon5.SelectedIndex = 0;
            txtTotalHoras.Value = "";
            txtHorasRazon1.Value = "";
            txtHorasRazon2.Value = "";
            txtHorasRazon3.Value = "";
            txtHorasRazon4.Value = "";
            txtHorasRazon5.Value = "";

            string message = "Registro de Asistencia Exitoso";
            this.AlertBoxMessage.InnerText = message;
            this.AlertBox.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exC)
        {

            throw new Exception("Error sometiendo horas de contrato " + ContratoProyeccionID, exC);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you describe what is not working?

Comment: I want something like an int count for in which it counts how many conditions get filled with values greater than 0 it lets the user submit the data. that is what I am missing and cannot figured out how to do it.

Comment: FYI - https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: So... you are looking for `int counter = 0; if (condition) { … counter++ }` ?

Comment: @RandRandom thanks but I prefer reading English. LOL

Comment: x-y. You want "form field validation". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972961.aspx

Comment: @randRandom Yes something like that

Comment: Since you only say "something like that", what is missing?

Comment: ok, the problem is that the If statements prevents data to be inserted on someterhoras method... but I need to prevent the user to update the database if there is no value submitted on someterhoras. So I have an insert and an Update here. But I should only update if at least one of the Someterhoras method in the if statements gets to insert.

Comment: So currently is the method SometerHoras doing the insert / update?

Comment: SometerHoras does an insert and in the code I posted is the Update

Comment: `else return;` ? Or `else throw new ArgumentException("Value must be > 0")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do that

```
    int counter;
    try
    {
        int razon = 0;
        counter = 0

        if (int.TryParse(txtTotalHoras.Value, out razon) && razon > 0)
        {
          SometerHoras(ContratoProyeccionID, decimal.Parse(txtTotalHoras.Value), 0); 
          counter ++;
        }
```

ecc....
Put counter++ inside every if and then you are done

Comment: No, do not. Use what ASP.net is already giving you: [User Input Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972961.aspx).

Comment: Yea, User Input Validation is better , my bad

Comment: I already have input validation, What I need is to not update database if there is no insert

Comment: @Naju You are doing a manual validation, but you do not handle the fail-branch. You can easily add `else` branches to those `if`s and jump out before touching the DB. BTW: A lot of code duplication. Better factor that out to a method.

Comment: this was what I was looking for, @matteocracco Thanks, it is now working correctly.